# cutree не делит на кластеры

Tags: r

Используя команду cutree, данные не делятся на кластеры, хотя на дендрограмме видно что делить есть что.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Функция `cutree` возвращает вектор с номером группы. Эти группы соответствуют веткам, выделенным красными прямоугольниками на дендрограмме.

Для примера используем данные `USArrests`.

```
# Загрузка пакетов
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggdendro)
library(ggplot2)

# Подготовка данных
x <- USArrests %>% 
    as_tibble() %>% 
    rownames_to_column("State")

# Иерархический кластерный анализ
hc <- x %>% 
    select_if(is.numeric) %>% 
    scale() %>% 
    dist() %>% 
    hclust()

# Добавление меток
hc$labels <- x$State[hc$order]

# Дендрограмма
plot(hc)
rect.hclust(hc, k = 4)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Теперь продемонстрируем, что выделенные с помощью `cutree` группы соответствуют графику выше.

```
# Добавление выделенных групп в исходные данным
groups <- hc %>%
    cutree(k = 4) %>% 
    as.data.frame() %>% 
    rownames_to_column("State") %>% 
    setNames(c("State", "Group")) %>% 
    mutate(Group = as.factor(Group))
x <- inner_join(x, groups)

# Подготовка данных
dendr_data <- dendro_data(hc, type = "rectangle")
labs <- label(dendr_data)
labs <- inner_join(labs, groups, by = c("label" = "State"))

# Дендрограмма с подсветкой выделенных групп
ggplot() +
    geom_segment(data = segment(dendr_data),
                 mapping = aes(x = x, y = y, xend = xend, yend = yend)) +
    geom_text(data = labs,
              mapping = aes(label = label, x = x, y = 0, colour = Group),
              angle = 90, vjust = 0, hjust = 0)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: и что дальше???